# why do i need to pass panel class as parameter in the ViewThread constructor..? 

Tags: android, parameters, constructor

```
         public class ViewThread extends Thread 
         {
            private Panel mPanel;
            private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
            private boolean mRun = false;

            public ViewThread(Panel panel) 
            {
               mPanel = panel;
               mHolder = mPanel.getHolder();
            }
```

Why do i need to pass `Panel` class as parameter in the `ViewThread` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor requires a `Panel` object, as Mitch already stated.
In case that you don't want that (although I guess there is a reason for it) you can simply write a second constructor like

```
         public class ViewThread extends Thread 
         {
            private Panel mPanel;
            private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
            private boolean mRun = false;

            public ViewThread(Panel panel) 
            {
               mPanel = panel;
               mHolder = mPanel.getHolder();
            }


            public ViewThread()
            {   
               // Do something constructive here, like
               mPanel = new Panel(); 
            }
```